# Appengine-datanucleus error on one to many fetch after server is restarted

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus, requestfactory

I have a project where I have a user that has a list of pages as Entities.  When I first create the user with the pages all the fetches work as expected, but after I restart the local_db.bin appengine-datanucleus server I receive an error when fetching the list of pages.  I am using request factory so I have the ID of the pages as a String - please correct me if this is wrong.  In the code below I am forcing the fetch of the page list, but in reality the list was loaded by the request factory code when the .with("pages") method was added to the request.  But the force loading of the pages causes the same error and it allows me to easily step into the code.
The error I get is **java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer**.  I have stepped through a lot of the datanucleus code and the error seems to be happening as the data from the store is loaded into the newly created class.  The only Integers in the class is the *version* and one field - both of which I tried making into Longs - clearing the database, recreating the data then restarting the server to which I got the same error.  My feeling is that it has something to do with making the id a String.

Either I have something set up wrong or there is a bug with the datanucleus JPA 2 support.  Hopefully someone will know the answer to this.  Below are the two entity classes and the service method that causes the error.

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "userIds") @SequenceGenerator(name = "userIds")
private Long id;
@Version private Integer version;

private String name = "";
private String lowerName = "";
private Date lastLoginDate;
private Date createDate;
private boolean isAdmin;

private String language = "en";
private String country = "US";
private String timezone = "EST";
private String theme = "HI";

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private List<Page> pages ;

private String startPageName = "";
public User() {
    createDate = new Date();
    pages = new ArrayList<Page>();
}
Plus some getters and setters.
```

And the Page Class

```
@Entity
public class Page {
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY) 
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true") 
private String id;
@Version private Integer version;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) private User user;

private String name = "";
private String description = "";
private Integer columnCount = 3;
@Enumerated private LayoutType layoutType = LayoutType.Col3StyleEven;
Plus some getters and setters.
```

And the method that will generate the error.

```
    public User getCurrentUser() {
    Long id = securityProvider.get().getUserId();
    if (id == null) {
        return null;
    }
    EntityManager em = emProvider.get();
    try {
        User user = em.find(User.class, id);

        List<Page> pages = user.getPages();  // Force loading
        return user;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.throwing(Service.class.getName(), "getCurrentUser", e);
        log.severe("Could not get user data: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**On Edit: Added a Stack Trace:**

> java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.TypeConversionUtils.datastoreValueToPojoValue(TypeConversionUtils.java:403)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchFieldFromEntity(FetchFieldManager.java:463)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:408)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2353)
>       at com.ihg.dashboard.server.domain.Page.jdoReplaceField(Page.java)
>       at com.ihg.dashboard.server.domain.Page.jdoReplaceFields(Page.java)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1935)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1962)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$1.fetchFields(EntityUtils.java:974)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadFieldValues(JDOStateManager.java:764)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.initialiseForHollow(JDOStateManager.java:205)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerFactory.newForHollowPopulated(StateManagerFactory.java:89)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactory.newForHollowPopulated(ObjectProviderFactory.java:75)
>       at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2882)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1014)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.getCollectionFromDatastoreObject(FetchFieldManager.java:680)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchRelationField(FetchFieldManager.java:483)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:405)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2353)
>       at com.ihg.dashboard.server.domain.IHGUser.jdoReplaceField(IHGUser.java)
>       at com.ihg.dashboard.server.domain.IHGUser.jdoReplaceFields(IHGUser.java)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1935)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1962)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.fetchObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:567)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadFieldsFromDatastore(JDOStateManager.java:1638)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadSpecifiedFields(JDOStateManager.java:1240)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.isLoaded(JDOStateManager.java:1728)
>       at com.ihg.dashboard.server.domain.IHGUser.jdoGetpages(IHGUser.java)
>       at com.ihg.dashboard.server.domain.IHGUser.getPages(IHGUser.java:209)
>       at com.ihg.dashboard.server.services.HplUIService.getCurrentIHGUser(HplUIService.java:188)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ReflectiveServiceLayer.invoke(ReflectiveServiceLayer.java:182)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.invoke(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:111)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.invoke(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:111)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.invoke(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:111)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.processInvocationMessages(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:463)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:233)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:135)
>       at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
>       at com.ihg.dashboard.server.DashboardServlet.doPost(DashboardServlet.java:61)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
>       at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

**On Edit 2:**
After setting a breakpoint where the exception is thrown I see it is the enumerated field that is causing the problem.  Something I am doing there is not right.

The code at the line the exception occurs is:

```
 value = enumClass.getEnumConstants()[(Integer)value];
```

So it seems value when read from the db is a Long,  but I'm guess that when it is kept in cache from a newly created entity it is an Integer.

**On Edit 3**

I change the enumerated field to

```
@Enumerated(STRING) private LayoutType layoutType = LayoutType.Col3StyleEven;
```

This stores the value as a String instead of Ordinal. It isn't as efficient as Ordinal but it will get me past this error.

Comment: one would normally expect any exception to be accompanied by a stack trace, because without any context, it means very little. PS, "datanucleus JPA2 support" you refer to is actually "GAE JPA support" since that is owned by Google, not the DataNucleus project, being separate

Comment: The requestFactory part was catching the exception and returning the error message that I gave in the post to the client,  but I will print out one and post it in the OP.  GAE does claim to have JPA 2 support now.  It isn't clear what is datanucleus code and what is gae code, though I know the mapper is called appengine-datanucleus-orm  So I thought it was a bit of both.  I could not find any info on what format or code the local_db.bin was from other than looking inside it and seeing google one step which I couldn't find any info on.

Comment: As shown above in the edits,the problem is with the enum handling.  It is in googles code com.google.appengine.datanucleus.TypeConversion. There seems to be a data mismatch between the stored Ordinal value Long and the pojo Integer value (line 403).

Comment: Good that you worked out in what block of code the problem lies. You could report it to https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/list  with a suitable testcase so they can see it or, better still, grab the code for that plugin and update it (so you don't have to wait for Google)

Comment: I may take a crack at fixing it and making a patch this weekend.  Should an Enumerated Ordinal be a Long or an Integer?  That determines which side of the mismatch I would look at fixing.

Comment: I'd guess at an "int" since java.lang.Enum.ordinal() returns an int, and can't remember what type it was stored in "Datastore" as ... likely in TypeConversionUtils somewhere

Comment: Thanks,  that will move the fix from the line I found to where it is stored in the datastore.